How to divide values in columns in one dataframe by the same value in another df in Pandas?
I want to divide all values from particular columns in the dataframe rpk by the same value from the dataframe scaling_factor, according to sample_name. I know how to do it for a particular value (e.g. for the column 'P1-6' in rpk all the values should be divided by 2 - according to value factor for 'P1-6' in scaling_factor dataframe) but how to do it for all samples?.
There is a part of input data:
import pandas as pd

rpk_data = {'P1-6': [1, 2, 3, 4],
            'P1-12': [2, 4, 6, 8],
            'P1-25': [6, 12, 3, 9]
            }
rpk = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rpk_data)

sc_f_data = {'sample': ['P1-6', 'P1-12', 'P1-25'],
             'factor': [1, 2, 3]
             }
scaling_factor = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sc_f_data)

divided_value = rpk.loc[0, 'P1-6'] / scaling_factor.loc[0, 'factor'] # will be 1

The desired output should look like this:
   P1-6  P1-12  P1-25
0     1      1      2
1     2      2      4
2     3      3      1
3     4      4      3


Create Series with index by sample column and divide:
out = rpk / scaling_factor.set_index('sample')['factor']
#out = rpk.div(scaling_factor.set_index('sample')['factor'])
print (out)
   P1-6  P1-12  P1-25
0   1.0    1.0    2.0
1   2.0    2.0    4.0
2   3.0    3.0    1.0
3   4.0    4.0    3.0

For integer division:
out = rpk // scaling_factor.set_index('sample')['factor']
print (out)
   P1-6  P1-12  P1-25
0     1      1      2
1     2      2      4
2     3      3      1
3     4      4      3

Be carefull, with different data integer division has different output:
rpk_data = {'P1-6': [1, 2, 3, 4],
            'P1-12': [2, 4, 6, 8],
            'P1-25': [5, 12, 3, 9]
            }
rpk = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rpk_data)

sc_f_data = {'sample': ['P1-6', 'P1-12', 'P1-25'],
             'factor': [1, 2, 3]
             }
scaling_factor = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sc_f_data)


out = rpk / scaling_factor.set_index('sample')['factor']
print (out)
   P1-6  P1-12     P1-25
0   1.0    1.0  1.666667
1   2.0    2.0  4.000000
2   3.0    3.0  1.000000
3   4.0    4.0  3.000000

out = rpk // scaling_factor.set_index('sample')['factor']
print (out)
   P1-6  P1-12  P1-25
0     1      1      1
1     2      2      4
2     3      3      1
3     4      4      3


Another possible solution, using div after creating a dictionary with the factors:
rpk.div(dict(zip(scaling_factor['sample'], scaling_factor['factor'])), axis=1)

Output:
   P1-6  P1-12  P1-25
0   1.0    1.0    2.0
1   2.0    2.0    4.0
2   3.0    3.0    1.0
3   4.0    4.0    3.0


For integer division, use floordiv instead of div:
rpk.floordiv(dict(zip(scaling_factor['sample'], scaling_factor['factor'])), axis=1)

Output:
   P1-6  P1-12  P1-25
0     1      1      2
1     2      2      4
2     3      3      1
3     4      4      3

